# Cómo impedir que se escriba más texto en emojioneArea

Tags: jquery, contador

He encontrado este magnífico ejemplo de [Banshi L. Dangi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4156401/banshi-l-dangi) de como añadir un contador de caracteres a una textarea con emoticonos de emojioneArea:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703854/2692665
Pero, ¿alguien sabe cómo hacer que al llegar al número máximo de caracteres no sea posible escribir más?
Gracias por la ayuda.
Saludos.

Código de la pregunta:

```
/*emojioneArea */
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#message").emojioneArea({
                       pickerPosition: "bottom",
                       tonesStyle: "bullet",
                       events: {
                         keyup: function (editor, event) {
                           console.log('event:keyup');
                           countChar(this);
                        }
                      }
               });
    }); 

   /*Character Counter */
        function countChar(val) {
            var len = val.getText().length;
            if (len >= 140) {
                  val.value = val.content.substring(0, 140);
                  $('#chars').text(0);
            } else {
                 $('#chars').text(140 - len);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, deberías añadir el código a tu pregunta ya que los enlaces pueden desaparecer, ¿qué ocurre si Blunick borra su pregunta? entonces no podríamos acceder al código mencionado.

Comment: En el keyup dónde se llama a countChar(this); deberías cambiarlo por algo así como c = countChar(this); y cambiar la función para que devuelva el número de caracteres, entonces si c = 0 cancela el keyup con event.preventDefault() o similar.

Comment: Eso lo he intentado ya pero por alguna razón que desconozco el event.preventDefault() no funciona dentro del keyup. Gracias de todos modos por la respuesta.

Comment: Ya he añadido el código, lamento el error, track3r. Como habréis adivinado no suelo publicar mucho por aquí, de ahí mi torpeza. Gracias por la advertencia. Un saludo.

Comment: Si no te importa, ¿podrías añadir tu código modificado con el intento del event.preventDefault()? prueba a realizar event = "", ya que mirando la documentación, parece que event no es el evento, sino la key pulsada, pero no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras rápidas respuestas. He probado con event="" y tampoco resultó. He probado incluso metiendo dentro del keyup solamente el  event.preventDefault(); creí que eso debería impedir que se tecleara nada en la textarea pero no hace nada.

Comment: Quita lo del event.preventDefault() y añade un return false;

Comment: Pues eso también lo he probado pero nada, parece que desde dentro del keyup no se puede detener la entrada de texto.Gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 1):

Bien pues me auto-contesto.
El problema está en el evento keyup. Como su nombre indica se ejecuta cuando la tecla está arriba, es decir, cuando ya se ha pulsado y se suelta. Esto implica que el caracter ya se ha pintado en la caja de texto y por eso el event.preventDefault() no sirve de nada.
La solución está en usar el evento keyup para el contador, puesto que así cuenta caracteres que ya están pintados y el evento keypress para ejecutar en el el event.preventDefault() si se ha sobrepasado el número de caracteres permitido.
El resultado sería algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var maxNumCharacters = 140;
     $("#message").emojioneArea({
                   pickerPosition: "bottom",
                   tonesStyle: "bullet",
                   events: {
                     keyup: function (editor, event) {
                       console.log('event:keyup');
                       countChar(this.getText());
                    },
                    keypress: function (editor, event){
                    if (this.getText().length>=maxNumCharacters){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    }
                  }
           });
           countChar( $('#message').val());
}); 

    function countChar(val) {
        var len = val.length;
        if (len >= 140) {
              val.value = val.content.substring(0, 140);
              $('#chars').text(0);
        } else {
             $('#chars').text(140 - len);
        }
    }
```

Mi error estaba por lo tanto en obsesionarme en el evento equivocado.
Os doy las gracias de todos modos, por haberme puesto en el camino correcto.
Un saludo.